# Membership provider not work well in my culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, simplemembership

The membership provider uses ToUpperInvarint() function for upper casing the userName, and it fails to found users have a culture specific letters, so not work well and throw exception.

for example: in Turkish culture, the upper case for "admin" is "ADMİN" with toUpper() method and is "ADMIN" with ToUpperInvariant() method. because the membership provider uses toUpperInvariant for userName and UPPER([userName]) in its SQL query it fails to found some users.

I don't know how to fix it, please guide me? thank you

```
if (membership.GetUser("admin", false) == null)
       membership.CreateUserAndAccount("admin", "admin123");
```

this code fail two times, first when user "admin" exist it cannot found it because : It searches in DB with this query:

```
SELECT [userID] from [User] WHERE (UPPER([userName]) = @0);
```

second, if the user not exist (or cannot found) tries to creat user "admin" and it is successful, but when tryies to create account for user "admin" again it tries to get "[userID]" with above sql query and it fails to found and throw exception. because "ADMIN != ADMİN"

my sql server (or my database) collation is Turkish-CI

Comment: Please add more details. Perhaps code. Have you tried changing the string collation?

Comment: dear @Aron, where can I change string collation?

Comment: collation is how SQL server decides to order/compare strings. Unfortunately the easiest point to change it is during installation.

Comment: That is exactly because of the collation, I change my Database collation to latin1_general_CI_AS and it works successfully, but this is not the solve for this problem, I think it is a bug for simplemembership provider of the asp.net. I don't want to change my db's collation for solving this problem.

Comment: The fact is for the username column you want `CI_AS` collation typically, since your program logic searches for usernames in a `CI_AS` way. [You might want to only set the collation on that one column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx)

Comment: is there any way to solve this problem in code (c#) and not DB?

Comment: The problem is a DB problem. You are looking for a user name in the DB. Without the correct collation on your indices, the DB will need to do a table scan to find your user. This is highly inefficient. So in short, there might be a way, but I would highly advise against it, since you would be running your happy case through a highly inefficient mechanism.